# Cannot access this in anonymous function

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am trying to convert the JSON of an interface given by an API to different arrays which consist of dedicated objects. The type of the object is given as an variable in the interface.

The interface:

```
export interface Interface{
  interfaceClassType: string;
}
```

I am accessing my json data like this:

```
getJSON(): Observable<Interface[]> {
    return this.http.get<Interface[]>(URL)
      .pipe(
        retry(2),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

This method is called like this:

```
 arrayWithObjects: Interface[];
 class1Array: Class1[];
 class2Array: Class2[];

 processJSON(): void {
    this.configService.getJSON().subscribe(results => this.arrayWithObjects = results);
    this.arrayWithObjects.forEach (function (object) {
      switch (object.interfaceClassType) {
        case "first":
          this.class1Array.push(object as Class1);
          break;
        case "second":
          this.class2Array.push(object as Class2);
          break;
      }
    }.bind(this))
  }
```

I get the same result when i call it like this:

```
 arrayWithObjects: Interface[];
 class1Array: Class1[];
 class2Array: Class2[];

 processJSON(): void {
    this.configService.getJSON().subscribe(results => this.arrayWithObjects = results);
    this.arrayWithObjects.forEach ((object) => {
      switch (object.interfaceClassType) {
        case "first":
          this.class1Array.push(object as Class1);
          break;
        case "second":
          this.class2Array.push(object as Class2);
          break;
      }
    })
  }
```

When I execute this methods i always get an error saying: `ERROR TypeError: this.class1Array is undefined`

Comment: the error is very clear. Where is defined your class1Array object?

Comment: use arrow function, not `function`: `forEach ((object) =>  { })`. There are so many examples of this question out there. But hard to track them down

Comment: I already looked at many similar questions and i already tried this way, but somehow this also doesn't work for me

Comment: @bena: You have 2 issues. You're trying to access the async variable `this.arrayWithObjects` synchronously and using `this` keyword in a JS `function` which will point to the scope of the function, not the class.

Comment: @MichaelD As a gold badge holder, you can close the question as a duplicate of both questions...

Comment: In the code you posted you don't ever give `class1Array` a value. The line `class1Array: Class1[];` is just declaring the variable, but not populating it. If you change it to `class1Array: Class1[] = [];` then you're also populating it (with an empty array). You can then push data into the array.

Comment: @Tim This actually solved my problem.

Comment: Good stuff :) I don't know why this question was closed as a duplicate, I have voted to reopen it. Perhaps people didn't read the error message you provided and just looked for problems in the code. Anyway, glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a normal function as callback won't preserve the scope of `this` inside it. Using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) will solve that.

```js
this.arrayWithObjects.forEach ((object) => {
      console.log(this.class1Array);
})
```

Comment: Why? What good does this do? Answers which explain a change made to code are better than those that simply regurgitate advice.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Using normal functions as callback wont preserve `this` scope.

Comment: I know. [Edit] your answer to provide the information to the OP and others who come across the answer. Stack Overflow is about providing lasting answers that help everyone who reaches the question and its answers, not just the OP. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues here.

1. `this.arrayWithObjects` is assigned asynchronously. By the time you do the `forEach` it still is unassigned. To solve it, move the `forEach` inside the subscription.

```js
processJSON(): void {
  this.configService.getJSON().subscribe(results => {
    this.arrayWithObjects = results;
    this.arrayWithObjects.forEach (
      ...
    );
}
```

More about async data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/6513921).

2. Use arrow function notation instead of conventional JS `function` to point the `this` keyword to the class member variables. In a JS `function`, `this` points to the scope of the function, not the class.

```js
processJSON(): void {
  this.configService.getJSON().subscribe(results => {
    this.arrayWithObjects = results;
    this.arrayWithObjects.forEach((object) => {       // <-- arrow function here
      switch (object.interfaceClassType) {
        case "first":
          this.class1Array.push(object as Class1);
          break;
        case "second":
          this.class2Array.push(object as Class2);
          break;
      }
    });               // <-- `bind()` not required
  });
}
```